# Is there a way to show a 3-D surface plot in the browser?

Tags: browser, plot, surf

I've got a bunch of data for 3-D surface plots. I want to build a quick web interface to let me browse through that data. Are there any (free) packages out there that can easily show surface plots? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829462/choosing-a-plotting-library-for-web-browser-application) question but the suggested libraries did not support surface plots.

If it requires a plugin like flash / java that is fine. This is for prototyping so a quick 'n dirty solution is preferred.

Right now, the only option I have come up with is to use gnuplot to serve up static images. It would be awesome if there was some way to provide an interactive 3-D surface plot in the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very recent versions of gnuplot seem to do exactly what you want: [HTML 5 canvas demo.](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_canvas/)

Comment: Wow, I didn't know gnuplot had added this terminal.  Marking this as the answer because it doesnt require a plugin (just HTML 5 canvas support) and is quick to implement.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a java applet? If you're using java you can use jogl (open gl library) which gives you 3D rendering.

Comment: I wanted something quick for prototyping.  If I wanted to go render the data from scratch myself this would be a good option.